# Root password set & my IP entered at Network IP required, But unable to connect

Tags: google-cloud-sql

The past similar questions have been related to mysql.
But this question is about using Google Cloud SQL, project name and access control, 1. set root password; then, 2. enter network IP.
From mysql workbench, "connect" command results in "access denied for user "root" nnn.nnn.nn.nnn (using password:YES).
Please help.   I must be doing something wrong!
Your help much appreciated!!!

Comment: Did you enabled the "Only allow SSL connection" ?

Comment: Thanks to Paolo P, after resetting password and network IP as 123.12.123.12 format and turning off "only allow SSL connection", clicking on "restart" button at gcs project where edit button is located, the connection from mysql workbench was successful.

Answer (score 0):

please double check that you enabled root password and that password is correct or try to change password.

If you get that error it means that your client (Mysql Workbech) can reach the SQL instance so networking and firewall rules are OK and even Cloud SQL access control is correctly set-up to receive request from your remote client IP otherwise you would receive a 'Lost connection at Mysql server' error.

Check e.g via whatismyipaddress.com that your client IP is not changing (Dynamic IP) and it is exactly the one you authorized in Cloud SQL access control.

Sincerely,
Paolo